# what this exception means in oracle jaxd-ws soap web service

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws

> javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: Unable to parse the incoming
>   request   at
>   com.sun.xml.ws.fault.SOAP11Fault.getProtocolException(SOAP11Fault.java:197)
>     at
>   com.sun.xml.ws.fault.SOAPFaultBuilder.createException(SOAPFaultBuilder.java:130)
>     at
>   com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:125)
>     at
>   com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:95)
>     at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(SEIStub.java:136)   at
>   $Proxy603.getdocumenttypes(Unknown Source)    at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)     at
>   weblogic.wsee.jaxws.spi.ClientInstanceInvocationHandler.invoke(ClientInstanceInvocationHandler.java:84)
>     at $Proxy599.getdocumenttypes(Unknown Source)   at
>   cmic.img.MSPlugin.getDocumentTypes(MSPlugin.java:164)     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)     at
>   com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$TypeOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:168)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:70)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:279)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:136)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:86)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:136)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:74)
>     at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl

Comment: It means that the server is unable to parse the incoming request :-) You should check and/or post the request message, it might be wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out the problem ..actually our client is using clustering of server with a load balancer. after investigating each ends, I found  |The SOAP envelope does not  have proper structure as expexted by web service. It is occuring when load balancer redirects request to a server. It has been resolved when I reinstalled the SOAP web service EAR FILE on server.